# Bus admittance matrix after the removal of reactance

Tags: power, mains, load

> The bus admittance matrix for a power system network is $$
>  \begin{bmatrix}-j39.9 & j20 & j20 \\j20 & -j39.9 & j20 \\ j20 &j20 &
>  -j39.9 \end{bmatrix} \text{pu}$$ There is a transmission line connected between buses 1 and 3 which is represented by the circuit
>   shown in figure
>
> [image: line]
>
> If the transmission line is removed from service, what is the modified
>   bus admittance matrix?
>
> 1. \$\begin{bmatrix}-j19.9 & j20 & 0 \\ j20 &-j39.9 & j20 \\ 0 & j20 & -j19.9 \end{bmatrix}\text{pu}\$
> 2. \$\begin{bmatrix}-j39.95 & j20 & 0 \\ j20 &-j39.9 & j20 \\ 0 & j20 & -j39.95 \end{bmatrix}\text{pu}\$
> 3. \$\begin{bmatrix}-j19.95 & j20 & 0 \\ j20 &-j39.9 & j20 \\ 0 & j20 & -j19.95 \end{bmatrix}\text{pu}\$
> 4. \$\begin{bmatrix}-j19.95 & j20 & j20 \\ j20 &-j39.9 & j20 \\ j20 & j20 & -j19.95 \end{bmatrix}\text{pu}\$

I'm confused between option (1) and (3). Since the sum of row in option (1) gives us \$-j0.1\$ so after removal of the branch the admittance matrix sum should still be \$-j0.1\$. Am I right ?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @user1831847 NO it's not homework. It was asked in my examination. So, I'm checking whether my answer are right or wrong before I could claim on the answers.

Comment: I suspect the only difference between (1) and (3) is the 0.05 pu susceptance.  (+ j 0.10) vs (+ j 0.05)

Comment: @user1831847 what should be the answer ?